# svelte with tailwind showing different output in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: firefox, tailwind-css, sveltekit

I was designing a **Tags** input field much like **StackOverflow**. I designed it using **[Sveltekit](https://kit.svelte.dev/)** and **[Tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/)**  . But it was showing different outputs in Firefox and Chrome. I searched through the code using debugger tools. As a result, I was unable to find any solution.

I designed this :

[image]

Code of this :

```
<script lang="ts">
     let TagObj: { Input: string; Focus: boolean; List: string[]; Suggested: string[] } = {
        Input: '' as string,
        Focus: false as boolean,
        List: [] as string[],
        Suggested: [] as string[]
    };
    / TAGS
    function onKeyPressTags(e: { keyCode: any }) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 32:
                onKeyTag();
                break;
            case 13:
                onKeyTag();
                break;
        }
    }
    function onKeyTag() {
        if (TagObj.Input.trim() != ("" as String)) {
            TagObj.List = [...TagObj.List, TagObj.Input.trim()];
            TagObj.Input = '' as string;
        }
    }

</script>

<div class="mx-4 mt-3 h-fit w-[95%] rounded-lg border-2 border-[#24262b] bg-[#303338] p-2 text-lg font-medium text-[#98999e]  outline-0   {TagObj.Focus ? 'border-sky-500' : ''}  ">
    <ul class="flex flex-row flex-wrap gap-2">
        {#each TagObj.List as t}
        <li class="m-1 rounded-md bg-[#3d4951] px-2 py-1 text-[#9bc0da] hover:cursor-pointer hover:bg-slate-600 hover:text-teal-200">
            {t}
        </li>
        {/each}
        <input on:keypress={onKeyPressTags} maxlength=20 bind:value={TagObj.Input} on:focus={() => { TagObj.Focus = true;}} on:blur={() => { TagObj.Focus = false; }} type="text" class=" inline w-fit grow bg-inherit  border-0  outline-0  " />
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is how chrome is showing :
[image]

This is how Firefox is showing :
[image]

A small blue border is showing around the input field in Firefox. I couldn't find the reason behind it. How i show the exact same UI in Firefox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be the `focus:outline` behavior that's different in Firefox than chrome.

See [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/350cc768f4924a2d817e09581a8e789b?version=3.48.0)

Adding `focus:outline-none` to the input gets rid of it.

```html
<input maxlength=20 type="text" class=" inline w-fit grow bg-inherit  border-0  outline-0 focus:outline-none" />
```

Sidenote: outlines are relevant pieces of functionality useful for a11y and keyboard users. So it is generally recommended to keep some form of physical indication when an input has focus and is active.